# How can I get the FULL list of slack emoji through API?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am using the slack API to get the full list of emoji, so that when I get a message, I will just replace `:squirrel:` with the icon.

The method `https://slack.com/api/emoji.list` works like a charm, but returns 30 icons only. I think this is correct since in the documentation page (https://api.slack.com/methods/emoji.list) they say:

> This method lists the custom emoji for a team.

Fair enough, but how can I get the full list of the associations icon-name / icon URL ?

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible :/

Comment: Thanks @qzb, do you have any link supporting your answer ?

Comment: Nope, I've just assumed that if it would be possible, such endpoints would be described in documentation. Also, `https://slack.com/api/emoji.list` endpoint doesn't support any pagination. If you want to be sure, you should [contact with slack team directly](https://grandparade.slack.com/help/requests/new), but I guess you already knew that.

Comment: Just got a response from their twitter: @stukki For now, that is the only public method we have. We're looking into some better methods for emoji in the future!

Comment: `https://your-workspace-name.slack.com/customize/emoji` - This url helped me to see which emojis I uploaded to slack for a given workspace. Although it is not through an API it might be helpful depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but if it's just about mapping images to slack-style names, this is a pretty good library:

https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data

So, building on the example in their README:

The emoji with the Slack style short name `point_up`has the hex value `261d`, and can thus be found here: https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data/blob/master/img-apple-160/261d.png

(Apple, because the default slack emoji are the apple emoji)

Comment: additionally: not extremely useful, but [this](https://a.slack-edge.com/f360/img/emoji_2016_06_08/sheet_apple_64_indexed_256colors.png) is the actual sprite Slack uses to display emoji.

Comment: Hey @wilhelm-klopp, thanks for the hint ! Yes this is very useful ! I found a JSON with all the possible matches and I am using it to get the unicode value and render the icon as HTML. I'll post the solution if it works out !

Comment: Also worth noting that this library is maintained by the Slack CTO

Answer (score 27):

I finally managed to get all the icons and to use them and I post here the solution for anyone that would like to use do similar:

1. First of all, I got the Slack **Custom** Emoji through [this](https://api.slack.com/methods/emoji.list) slack URL
2. Since at step 1 we get only Custom Emojis, it is useful to know that slack uses standard emoji defined in unicode characters, mapped through custom handles like `:smiley:` or `:horse:`. The good thing is that we can find, linked through slack page a [link to a JSON object with all the emoji mappings](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamcal/emoji-data/master/emoji.json). This file is HUGE, but has everything we need.
3. In the file you'll find an array of javascript object like the one below:

```js
{
 "name":"SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH",
 "unified":"1F603",
 "variations":[],
 "docomo":"E6F0", 
 "au":"E471",
 "softbank":"E057",
 "google":"FE330",
 "image":"1f603.png",
 "sheet_x":26,
 "sheet_y":18,"
 short_name":"smiley",
 "short_names":["smiley"],
 "text":":)",
 "texts":["=)","=-)"],
 "category":"People",
 "sort_order":5,
 "has_img_apple":true,
 "has_img_google":true,
 "has_img_twitter":true,
 "has_img_emojione":true
}
```

I used the following information:

- **shortnames** are the names that are used in slack (you'll need to turn `smiley` into `:smiley:` )
- **unified** is the unicode character to use (to use it directly in an HTML page you'll need to add `&#x` so in this case you'll have to use `&#x1F603;` which is rendered 😃

Using this information you will be able to create a slack-to-html function to decode emojis and display them wherever you want

Comment: I played around with that file and threw this together in case anyone wants to use it/modify it: https://gist.github.com/jthoward64/fc03eeb6780c118c921c511b9fff39b5

Answer (score 6):

Just extending on @Luca's awesome solution, I've created a `shortnames` => `html unicode` javascript dictionary...

#### Download: [Slack emoticons to unicode html mapping](https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/f3f27874d306a5d5048f02f0d3e14c07).

Generated - 17th August 2018 from the source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamcal/emoji-data/master/emoji.json

***Example:***

```js
{
  "+1": "&#x1F44D;",
  "-1": "&#x1F44E;",
  "100": "&#x1F4AF;",
  "1234": "&#x1F522;",
  "8ball": "&#x1F3B1;",
  "ab": "&#x1F18E;",
  "abc": "&#x1F524;",
  "abcd": "&#x1F521;",
  "accept": "&#x1F251;",
  ...
  "zebra_face": "&#x1F993;",
  "zipper_mouth_face": "&#x1F910;",
  "zombie": "&#x1F9DF;",
  "zzz": "&#x1F4A4;"
}
```

Which becomes...

```
{
  "100": "",
  "1234": "",
  "+1": "",
  "-1": "",
  "8ball": "",
  "ab": "",
  "abc": "",
  "abcd": "",
  "accept": "",
...
  "zebra_face": "",
  "zipper_mouth_face": "",
  "zombie": "",
  "zzz": ""
}
```

Comment: Great work! But I've update the list, since I was missing a lot of them. https://gist.github.com/harmjanluth/ba3a38491dbbb11828f4b023becd1d64

There are no variations in here, don't know how to map/deal with them converting to html unicode.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no API endpoint or comprehensive list of supported emoji/keywords available. I was able to grab the full set (including custom emoji for the workspace) by inspecting the Slack emoji picker using React Developer Tools (Chrome extension).

Here's an example (JSON):

```
...
  {
    "name": "beers",
    "unicode": "1f37b",
    "id": "E1f37b",
    "keywords": ["bar", "beer", "clink", "drink", "mug", "ale", "food"]
  },
  {
    "name": "baby_bottle",
    "unicode": "1f37c",
    "id": "E1f37c",
    "keywords": ["baby", "bottle", "drink", "milk", "infant"]
  },
  {
    "name": "knife_fork_plate",
    "unicode": "1f37d-fe0f",
    "id": "E1f37d-fe0f",
    "keywords": ["cooking", "fork", "knife", "plate"]
  },
  {
    "name": "champagne",
    "unicode": "1f37e",
    "id": "E1f37e",
    "keywords": ["bar", "bottle", "cork", "drink", "popping"]
  },
  { "name": "popcorn", "unicode": "1f37f", "id": "E1f37f", "keywords": [] },
...
```

Full dump *(as of 12/20/2020, excluding custom emoji)*: https://gist.github.com/impressiver/87b5b9682d935efba8936898fbfe1919

Answer (score 1):

Since it seemed impossible to find a complete and up-to-date source for these emoji names I came up with this browser console script. Just let it run in Slack and when it finishes it will download a full `emoji.json`. At time of writing it contains 2485 entries.

https://gist.github.com/8461e125072c2806301403a4e1eca891

This looks like this:

```json
{
  "+1": "https://a.slack-edge.com/production-standard-emoji-assets/13.0/google-medium/1f44d@2x.png",
  "+1::skin-tone-2": "https://a.slack-edge.com/production-standard-emoji-assets/13.0/google-medium/1f44d-1f3fb@2x.png",
  "+1::skin-tone-3": "https://a.slack-edge.com/production-standard-emoji-assets/13.0/google-medium/1f44d-1f3fc@2x.png",
  "+1::skin-tone-4": "https://a.slack-edge.com/production-standard-emoji-assets/13.0/google-medium/1f44d-1f3fd@2x.png",
```

If you want the actual emoji instead of the image you can parse that out of the image file name, e.g. `1f44d-1f3fd@2x.png` is `"\u1f44d\u1f3fd"`.